# Querying the latest date for each source column

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I created a two-column table with this query:

```
SELECT date, source FROM table
ORDER BY source ASC, date DESC
```

Result looks like this:

```
date                    source
2015-08-11 12:00:01 PM  source1            
2015-08-11 08:00:02 AM  source1
2015-08-11 12:00:19 PM  source2
2015-08-11 08:00:18 AM  source2
2015-08-10 06:00:38 AM  source3
2015-08-10 06:00:38 AM  source3
```

I want to select each row with the latest date for each source. Result would look like this:

```
date                    source
2015-08-11 12:00:01 PM  source1            
2015-08-11 12:00:19 PM  source2
2015-08-10 06:00:38 AM  source3
```

How do I achieve that result?

The purpose of this table is to give me an overview of the statuses of each source. If a source's latest row does not have a date that's similar to the others, that suggests a problem with the source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can just do this:

```
SELECT MAX(date), source FROM table
GROUP BY source
```

Comment: I tried MAX(date) once before, but with ORDER BY instead of GROUP BY, which returned only one row. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`SELECT source,max(date) FROM table group by source`